# Can you update serial number of the iOS-wallet pass?

Tags: ios, serialization, coupon, wallet

Can you update serial number of the installed iOS-wallet pass?
The Wallet Developer Guide states that you can update some fields of the wallet pass but does not say whether you can update any field. Also I know that serial number is used to send update-notification, so, will changing the serial number break the update process?
I have not found the answer using Wallet Developer Guide. Can someone help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is no.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html) lists only 2 fields that cannot be changed; the `serialNumber` and `passTypeIdentifier`.  The combination of these two fields creates a unique key which is used in a number of internal and external APIs to explicitly identify the pass in the wallet.

> The combination of pass type identifier and serial number is used
>   throughout PassKit to uniquely identify a pass. Two passes of the same
>   type with the same serial number are understood to be the same pass,
>   even if other information on them differs. For example, when a pass is
>   updated, the new version has the same pass type identifier and serial
>   number as the old version, so the new version replaces the old
>   version.

If your web service returns a serial that is different to the serial requested in the *Getting the Latest Version of a Pass* request, then the device will reject that pass.

The only option open to you is to install a new pass with the new serial number and delete the old pass.  If you are interacting via an app, it is possible to automate this (although will still require a user action to install the updated pass), if not, you will need to guide your users through the process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more thing: from what I understand you can count the number of devices the same pass is installed on, right? You just need to count the number of registration requests with the same serialNumber and different deviceLibratyID. Will it work?

Comment: Sort off.  The trouble is that Apple regularly rotates the device ids and tokens.  Each time that happens, you get a new registration request, but don't get a de-registration request.  You only get to know if a token is invalid when you try to push to it.  So if you are not regularly pushing updates to your passes or not managing the responses, then aver time, your registrations will slowly increase above the actual number of phones holding the pass.

Answer (score 0):

The `bundleID` is used to identify which App the pass belongs to.. The `SerialNumber` is to identify which pass it is that needs updating or changing..

You can have multiple passes per app and to distinguish them, we use the serial number. You can't change the serial number `easily`. I mean, you can install the pass as a new pass with a new serial number and delete the old one (additional logic such as above, would require a new release of your app). That's about it. You can't just change the serial number alone.

One option that doesn't currently work, would have been to update the old pass with an expiration date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You can have the same pass (with the same serial number) installed on multiple devices, right? Can you update just one of them using the right push address and leave others untouched?

Comment: No that's not possible. If you update a pass, it doesn't update just for "device". It updates for all devices that have that pass installed. I mean, you could specifically check the deviceLibraryIdentifier and see which device is adding the pass but this is not a common thing to do..

Comment: So, if I check the deviceLibraryIdentifier, can I "count" the number of devices with the particular pass installed?